# How to copy selected folders, subfolders and files from openFileDialog in c#

Tags: c#, file, copy, openfiledialog

I have a function that is suposed to copy all folders, subfolders files selected from openFileDialog from a location to another:

I've made this function to copy all the selected paths:

```
 public void CopiarFicheiros(string CopyTo, List<string> FilesToCopy )
        {

            foreach (var item in FilesToCopy)
            {
                string DirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(item);
                string Copy = Path.Combine(CopyTo, DirectoryName);
                if (Directory.Exists(Copy) && DirectoryName.ToLower() != "newclient" && DirectoryName.ToLower() != "newservice")
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Copy);
                    File.Copy(item, Copy + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(item), true);
                }
                else File.Copy(item, CopyTo + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(item), true);
            }

        }
```

The logic is full of flaws and I'm running out of time and can't seem to find a proper solution to this.

This is how I get the selected files and folders from the dialog:

```
  private List<string> GetFiles()
        {
            var Files = new List<string>();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string sFileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
                string[] arrAllFiles = openFileDialog.FileNames;
                Files = arrAllFiles.ToList();
            }
            return Files;
        }
```

Does anyone have a better solution or a clue to what I need to change to successfully do this?
Any help is highly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `OpenFileDialog` to choose the folder. As the name suggests, it not made for that task. You want the [`FolderBrowserDialog` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) for this task.

[How to: Copy Directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// Copy from the current directory, include subdirectories.
DirectoryCopy(".", @".\temp", true);
```

---

```
private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
    // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```